# How can I make a settings page affect multiple forms?

Tags: c#

I am building a game for a school project. I don't think I can call a function from my settings page on my main page, so how can I make my settings page affect the other forms in my project?

I haven't started coding my form as I'm still designing all of the forms, but I don't think I'll be able to call functions from one form in another form. For example (don't ask why) but as a joke/easter egg I want a button to change the game's text into Russian. How can I make it so that when I press a button in one form, it affects all of the others?

I haven't tried anything yet, as I'm still designing.

EDIT: I’m working with Visual Studio 2015, sorry for leaving that out. This is my first post so don’t crucify me to hard.

Comment: Are you asking about localization? Google for "localization winforms" or what UI you are using.

Comment: Using real localization is a large undertaking just for an Easter egg so you might very well just want to fake this, however; it IS a good thing to know how to localize.  As far as what you are describing about the settings themselves?.. What you need is a settings class all of the forms share (perhaps singleton) with a event/delegate for the forms to update their settings.  Each form would need to wire an event handler to the delegate.  When the settings change, have the settings class itself fire off the delegate and they all do their thing.

Comment: Pages? Sounds like you plan a website based game... what technique, what server, database? How long should the easter egg be effective after the user pressed a button somewhere? Session, hours, years, forever? Who should be affected - the user who pressed the button or everyone who plays the game? Missing a lot of information here.

Comment: To accomplish this, you either need [something common between the forms] like a parent form, or a web server, or a reference between these forms (perhaps the JS object "opener").  Let us know if you have either/both of these so we can narrow-down suggestions (to something that could work)